# Body appearing in header?

Tags: html, css

Trying to add content to my body to continue the flow of my site, but anything placed in the body is appearing in the top-left of the header.

Any ideas for why this may be happening?

Stack overflow wants me to write more content.
Here's me writing more content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="flex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Frank+Ruhl+Libre:wght@500">

    </head>

    <header>
        <div id="header">
            <h1 class="title">brookfield corp</h1>
            <nav class="top-nav">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#recent"><li>recent</li></a>
                    <a href="#samples"><li>samples</li></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <body>
        <h2>recent</h2>
    </body>

</html>
```

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
    font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4em;
    background-color: hsla(140, 50%, 30%, .9);
    color:cornsilk; 
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

nav {
    font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    color: black;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    opacity: .7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This block:

```
<header>
    <div id="header">
        <h1 class="title">brookfield corp</h1>
        <nav class="top-nav">
            <ul>
                <a href="#recent"><li>recent</li></a>
                <a href="#samples"><li>samples</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Needs to move within

`<body> </body>`

Then you could continue, before closing `</body>` tag, with `<div id="body">` or similar, following your `<header></header>` block.

Comment: Hi. I've put the header in the body like you've said, but for some reason my h2 is still appearing inside the header. I can't figure out what it could be. I'm messing around with the CSS and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: @neesam your `<nav>` element is `float`ed but this float is not cleared. You should add, after closing `</nav>` tag, something like: `<br clear="all" />` or `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` which will return flow to normal and the following content, in this case `<h2>`, will not be within header.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<header>` needs to be inside your `<body>`. Then have a `<div>` for you main content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="flex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Frank+Ruhl+Libre:wght@500">

    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="header">
                <h1 class="title">brookfield corp</h1>
                <nav class="top-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <a href="#recent"><li>recent</li></a>
                        <a href="#samples"><li>samples</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="main">
            <h2>recent</h2>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi. I've put the header in the body like you've said, but for some reason my h2 is still appearing inside the header. I can't figure out what it could be. I'm messing around with the CSS and nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove absolute position from `.title`

I also fixed up your `body` tags. All your content should be inside these tags

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="flex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Frank+Ruhl+Libre:wght@500">

    </head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="header">
            <h1 class="title">brookfield corp</h1>
            <nav class="top-nav">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#recent"><li>recent</li></a>
                    <a href="#samples"><li>samples</li></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    
        <h2>recent</h2>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
    font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4em;
    background-color: hsla(140, 50%, 30%, .9);
    color:cornsilk; 
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

nav {
    font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    color: black;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    opacity: .7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is sufficient solution as it will bring nav bar to down too

Comment: Also, if you dont want the whitespace around your nav. Take away the margin from the body. `body {
  margin: 0;
}`

Comment: @Dhara To be honest, this had me stumped

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  background-color: hsla(140, 50%, 30%, .9);
  color: cornsilk;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 height:fit-content;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  font-family: 'Frank Ruhl Libre', serif;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  opacity: .7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="flex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Frank+Ruhl+Libre:wght@500"> </head>
<header>
  <div id="header">
    <h1 class="title">brookfield corp</h1>
    <nav class="top-nav">
      <ul>
        <a href="#recent">
          <li>recent</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#samples">
          <li>samples</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<body>
  <h2>recent</h2>
</body>

</html>
```